# Is there a reason why filter-branch running rm won't delete all of the files in a list?

Tags: git

```
 git filter-branch --force --prune-empty --index-filter \
   "git rm --cached -r --force --ignore-unmatch -- $file" 
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I tried this with a rather long list of pathnames (44 of them) in $file. At the end of the run, some of them are not deleted. If I run again with the leftovers, they get deleted.

Why would this be?

Comment: Sure seems like it should work.  There's no weird shell-interpreted characters in the expansion of `$file`, I assume?  (Even if there were it seems unlikely that they'd change expansions on the second run.)

Comment: I found a blog post claiming that this routinely fails unless you split it into batches of four items.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving that list to a file, and then do:

```
xargs -a /tmp/files git rm --cached -r --force --ignore-unmatch --
```